# How to make the right conditions using firebase authentication in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I created a simple form to using firebase authentication with react native. But when I try, my `state` always show success even `failed` to auth.

`Success label` always appear `before` then followed by a `failed label`. Although in fact the same enter the wrong password with the correct email.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
//import libraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common';
import firebase from 'firebase';

// create a component
class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = { email: '', password:'', error: '', success: '', loading: false };

    onButtonPress() {

        const {email, password} = this.state;

        if(this.state.email == '') {
            this.setState({ error: 'Email can not be empty', loading: false });
        } else if(this.state.password == '') {
            this.setState({ error: 'Password can not be emptyg', loading: false });
        } else if(!this.validateEmail(this.state.email)) {
            this.setState({ error: 'Email not valid', loading: false });
        } else {

            this.setState({ error: '', success: '', loading: true });

            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(this.onLoginSuccess())
            .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(this.onLoginSuccess())
                .catch(() => {
                    this.onLoginFail()
                });
            });
        }
    }

    validateEmail = (email) => {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
    };

    onLoginFail() {
        this.setState({
            error: 'Authentication failed.',
            loading: false, 
        });
    }

    onLoginSuccess() {
        this.setState({
            loading: false, 
            error: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            success: 'Authentication success.',
        });
    }

    renderButton() {
        if(this.state.loading) {
            return <Spinner />;
        }
        return (
            <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Log In</Button>
        );
    }

    renderError() {
        if(this.state.error) {
            return <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
                {this.state.error}
            </Text>;
        }
    }

    renderSuccess() {
        if(this.state.success) {
            return <Text style={styles.successTextStyle}>
                {this.state.success}
            </Text>;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Card>
                    <CardSection>
                        <Input
                            placeholder="email@gmail.com"
                            label="Email"
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChangeText={ email => this.setState({ email })}
                        />
                    </CardSection>

                    <CardSection>
                        <Input
                            secureTextEntry
                            placeholder="password"
                            label="Password"
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChangeText={ password => this.setState({ password })}
                        />
                    </CardSection>

                    { this.renderError() }

                    { this.renderSuccess() }

                    <CardSection>
                        { this.renderButton() }
                    </CardSection>
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    errorTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: 'red'
    },
    successTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: 'green'
    }
};

//make this component available to the app
export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the state.error and state.success are neither empty strings.

```
renderError() {
        if(this.state.error && this.state.error !== '') {
            return <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
                {this.state.error}
            </Text>;
        }
    }

    renderSuccess() {
        if(this.state.success && this.state.success !== '') {
            return <Text style={styles.successTextStyle}>
                {this.state.success}
            </Text>;
        }
    }
```

The other option is to set to null said values when setting them out, so you won't need the not empty string condition.

Also, use identity operators (===) instead of quality operators (==).

```
onButtonPress() {

        const {email, password} = this.state;

        if(this.state.email === '') {
            this.setState({ error: 'Email can not be empty', loading: false });
        } else if(this.state.password === '') {
            this.setState({ error: 'Password can not be emptyg', loading: false });
        } else if(!this.validateEmail(this.state.email)) {
            this.setState({ error: 'Email not valid', loading: false });
        } else {

            this.setState({ error: '', success: '', loading: true });

            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(this.onLoginSuccess())
            .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(this.onLoginSuccess())
                .catch(() => {
                    this.onLoginFail()
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Dez's I'll try

Comment: I have just seen you have more equality operators. Better use identity ones. I will udpdate the answer.

Comment: Do you get any error? Also you are not binding your methods and the way you define validateEmail is sketchy from my point of view.